# Listening to outgoing/incoming calls

Tags: android

I'm a newbie android developer, I'm trying to develop an application; a background service which listens to incoming/outgoing calls/messages. I want to learn how to:

- I want to end the phone calls from specific numbers
- Delete the messages from Inbox/drafts/sent items

May I get some leads to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some tutorials out there, you should really try to do things before asking, you learn through trying, not copying, just to get you started:

[Reacting on SMS entry](http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/recognize-react-on-incoming-sms-t295.html)

Comment: Thank you Blindstuff!
I got my SMS thingy worked ! I'm lookin for telephony stuff let me know if you any such leads

Comment: That website has a lot of information, search around, i havent personally done any telephony listening, so I cant point you to anything specific. Since you're new to stackoverflow, if you found the answer useful you should either up vote it, or mark it as accepted.